# UINavigationController title in iOS seems corrupted

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, title, modalviewcontroller

When I present a UINavigationController modally and then push (without animation) some UIViewcontrollers onto it, the finally shown navigationItem.title is different from what I would expect.

I tried to narrow my issue down and came up with the following short code to duplicate the issue:

```
@implementation DummyRootVC
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    UINavigationController* nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[Dummy1VC alloc] init]];
    [self presentViewController:nc
                           animated:false
                         completion:nil];
}
@end

@implementation Dummy1VC
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    self.navigationItem.title= @"DUMMY1";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[Dummy2VC alloc] init] 
                                         animated:false];
}
@end

@implementation Dummy2VC
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.title= @"DUMMY2";
    self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[Dummy3VC alloc] init] 
                                         animated:false];
}
@end

@implementation Dummy3VC
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor orangeColor];
    self.navigationItem.title= @"DUMMY3";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[Dummy4VC alloc] init] 
                                         animated:false];
}
@end

@implementation Dummy4VC
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.title= @"DUMMY4";
    self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    for (UIViewController* vc in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
        NSLog(@"VC Stack: %@ Title:%@",vc,vc.navigationItem.title);
    }
    NSLog(@"End");
}
@end
```

In AppDelegate I set:

```
 self.window.rootViewController = [[DummyRootVC alloc] init];
```

When running that code the displayed title is „Dummy 2“ and the back-button is named „Dummy 4“, while I actually would expect a title „Dummy 4“ and a back-button named „Dummy 3“.

The log shows as expected the correct ViewController-Stack and the backgroundColor is (as expected) green (and interestingly is still green after one "back" click):

> VC Stack:  Title:DUMMY1
>
> VC Stack:  Title:DUMMY2
>
> VC Stack:  Title:DUMMY3
>
> VC Stack:  Title:DUMMY4
>
> End

I could work around that issue since it seems somewhat related to the non-animation setting in combination with presenting the navigation controller modally, but I would like to understand the underlying issue…

Can anyone provide me with some insight? Is this some bug or am I doing (as I suspect) just something the wrong way?

Thanks!

Comment: You can set breakpoint and see which line is called first

Comment: @Tj3n I did and the order of the methods being called is just as expected.

Comment: It's just in my practice that calling push/present...in `viewDidLoad` is never a good idea, many weird behavior happened, so i suggest call it in `viewWillAppea` or `viewDidAppear`, why then im not sure also

Comment: @Tj3n You are right. Moving those push calls into viewWillAppear did resolve the issue. (While I thought I already tested this earlier, I must have missed something back then...)  So, thank you! (Care to place your comment as an answer so that I may accept it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the push/present from `viewDidLoad` to `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` so that the viewController can init it's subview correctly to avoid problem :D